# Using 0x Swap can I build a system that will swap and transfer tokens between two addresses?

Tags: 0x

I'm hoping to build a system that would let me, in one transaction, transfer ETH from WalletA and receive DAI in Wallet B.

Is that possible with 0x Swap or any other 0x product?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with 0xAPI.

0xAPI takes funds from the taker, exchanges those funds and returns them to the taker.

For functionality like this you may wish to deploy your own custom contract.

Comment: Thanks @jacob-evans! not the answer I wanted but still appreciate it!

Comment: Jacob.
Your idea can be implemented.
I have already done this. I built smart contracts and javascript code that allow users to swap from eth to dai.
If you want, I will share you my code.
Good luck